# Interpreting the results of a regression with an interaction

Tags: multiple-regression, interaction, regression-coefficients

I'm having some trouble with interpreting the output of a regression and showing why (I think) it makes sense.
Assume I am regressing the price of a good on a dummy (e.g. whether the good was sold in a specific region), a continuous variable (e.g., the cost of production) and their interaction. Something like:

```
y= a +b1*I+ b2C+b3*I*C
```

Where I=1 if the good was sold in Region A, and equals 0 if sold in region B. C is the cost of production.
Now, I get my estimates. Something like:
b1= 0.17
b2=0.05
b3=-0.03.

Everything is statistically significant. I know that the average cost of production is LOWER in Region A, so it makes sense to me that b3 is negative. My issue now arises when I want to estimate the effect of selling in region A, everything else equal. If I take the derivative with respect to I, I would get: 0.17-0.03*C. This means that the price in Region A would be higher (due to b1) but decrease in the cost of production, compared to selling price in Region B. But I know that prices are not equal, and in fact they are higher in Region B.

As I am looking at the difference between Region A and Region B, my immediate (but likely very wrong) idea would be to look at the difference also in cost of production between the two region, and use that delta instead of C; this does not seem correct. Is there a way to numerically show that we should, somehow, consider the difference in the average level of costs of production?

Apologies if I was not clear!

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to CV.  You wrote

> I know that the average cost of production is LOWER in Region A, so it
> makes sense to me that b3 is negative.

This is not what an interaction means. The interaction means that the relationship between cost and price is different in the two regions. Since you are getting a negative parameter estimate for the interaction and a positive estimate for cost of materials, it means that the relationship between cost of materials and price is weaker in region A than in region B.  It also means that the relationship between region and price is weaker at higher costs.

> My issue now arises when I want to estimate the effect of selling in
> region A, everything else equal.

When there is an interaction, the effect of region is different at different prices. So, this question has no general answer.

A good way of getting a sense of this is to plug in a  few sets of reasonable  numbers for cost and then doing the calculation. You can also make a graph of the results. If you put cost on the x axis and price on the y axis, you can make a line for region A and another line for region B. These will not be parallel (that's another way of saying there is an interaction).